# Getting a "RuntimeError: Cannot close a running event loop" when creating a Telegram bot to edit a Google Sheet (v13.3 vs v20.0)

Tags: python-3.x, bots, telegram, event-loop

learning coder here - first time posting on SA.

I am writing code so that a telegram bot can populate a Google Sheet for me based off messages sent to it.

I have been stuck on a running event loop error for a couple of days, I think it is because the code (sourced and edited from online examples) is from python-telegram-bot-version 13.3 but it has since been updated to version 20.0.

So my code needs to be updated to 20.0, per transition guide [here](https://stackoverflow.com)

I thought I had done all of it correctly but I am stuck now. Apologies if novice question but any tips would be recommended. Below is my code:

```
from telegram.ext import Updater, CommandHandler, MessageHandler, filters, Application
from telegram import Bot
from aiogram.types import Message
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

# Set up Telegram bot
bot_token = '' # (Removed for security)
bot = Bot(token=bot_token)

# Set up Google Sheets
scope = ['https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive']
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('', scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds) #(Removed for security)

# Use Google Sheet ID to open the spreadsheet
sheet_id = '' # (Removed for security)
spreadsheet = client.open_by_key(sheet_id)

# Access the specific worksheet within the Google Sheet by its title
worksheet_title = "Website Data"  
worksheet = spreadsheet.worksheet(worksheet_title)

# Define your message handler function
async def add_to_google_sheet(message: Message):
    user_id = message.from_user.id
    text = message.text
    worksheet.append_row([user_id, text])

def main():
    # Create the Application instance
    application = Application.builder().bot(bot).build()

    # Add a message handler to the application
    application.add_handler(MessageHandler(filters.TEXT & ~filters.COMMAND,     add_to_google_sheet))

   # Run the bot
    application.run_polling()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```